# PHP Array Comparison of Keys and Values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that I am trying to find the differences / similarities between the two.

Here is the arrays:

```
   [781]=>
   array(7) {
     ["Pri_ID"]=>
     string(3) "781"
     ["Type"]=>
     string(7) "Athlete"
     ["EntryDate"]=>
     string(10) "2013-04-15"
     ["Status"]=>
     string(6) "Active"
     }
    [782]=>
    array(7) {
    ["Pri_ID"]=>
    string(3) "782"
    ["EntryDate"]=>
    string(10) "2013-04-15"
    ["Status"]=>
    string(7) "Removed"
    }
```

here is the second array:

```
      [780]=>
      array(7) {
      ["Pri_ID"]=>
      string(3) "781"
      ["EntryDate"]=>
      string(10) "2013-04-15"
      ["Status"]=>
      string(7) "Removed"
      }
      [782]=>
      array(7) {
      ["Pri_ID"]=>
      string(3) "782"
      ["EntryDate"]=>
      string(10) "2013-04-15"
      ["Status"]=>
      string(7) "Active"
      }
```

Notice that the key in the second array (780 ) does not exist in the first array. Also notice that the 'status' of array number two (id 782 )is now 'active' but was originally  in a status of removed.

The overall goal of this project is to compare the two arrays, located any differences, then placed these differences in either and array or a string and email the differences. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$Deleted[] = array_diff_assoc($myarrayOld, $myarrayNew);
$Added[] = array_diff_assoc($myarrayNew, $myarrayOld);
```

This will pick up the changes between the array keys, but not the statuskeys of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an recursive function like this

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2) {
    $difference=array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            if( !isset($array2[$key]) || !is_array($array2[$key]) ) {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                if( !empty($new_diff) )
                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
            }
        } else if( !array_key_exists($key,$array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value ) {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $difference;
}
```

Reference: [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php#111675)

Answer (score 0):

Here a small code to compare 2 arrays.

```
function compareAssociativeArrays($first_array, $second_array)
{
$result = array_diff_assoc($first_array, $second_array);
if(!empty($result))
{
//Arrays are different
//print_r($result); will return the difference as key => value pairs.
return FALSE;
}
else
{
//Arrays are same.
//print_r($result); returns empty array.
return TRUE;
}
}

//Usage:
$first = array(
'name' => 'Zoran',
'smart' => 'not really'
);

$second = array(
'smart' => 'not really',
'name' => 'Zoran'
);

if(compareAssociativeArrays($first, $second))
{
echo 'Arrays are same';
}
else
{
echo 'Arrays are different';
}
```